# How to change DNS server IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp, configuration, console

How can I change the DNS server IP address in Windows XP from command line?
I don't want to do it from UI every time I need since it requires a lot clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a command prompt:

`netsh interface ip set dns "local area connection" static 10.0.0.1`

You can list the interfaces on your PC using:

`netsh interface ip show interfaces`

Answer (score 4):

FYI, You can update both the primary and secondary dns servers by using the following commands

```
netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=10.0.0.1 register=PRIMARY
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=10.0.0.2 index=2
```

Comment: @Aaron I think second command has syntax error, index is not recognized in XP

Comment: @erdogany Really?  That might be an XP thing because i just ran it on windows 2003 and it worked.

Comment: Actually it works, take note that the 2nd one is `add dns` not `set dns`. I had the same problem earlier using `set dns` and it complaint that `index` is not a valid argument

Comment: thank you for highlighting this! I was also getting " 'index' is not a valid argument for this command."